# Providing Access to a Class Private Member Attributes

Tags: c#

I was wondering what is more efficient or the best practice for returning attributes of private members. For example:

```
class Foo
{
  private List<int> fooList;
  public Foo()
  {
    Random random = new Random();
    fooList = new List<int>(random.Next(1, 100));
  }
  // 
  public int Count { get { return fooList.Count; } }
  // or
  public int Count() { return fooList.Count; }
}
```

Which is best if I do not want to give public access to my list?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you should stay with a property. Because the `fooList.Count` is a property.